# Can a thread call .WaitOne() of a Mutex more than once before calling .ReleaseMutex() and vice versa?

Tags: c#, mutex, recursive-mutex

In my code, it would be convenient if my thread calls .WaitOne() more than once before calling .ReleaseMutex().

And vice versa:  Calling .ReleaseMutex() a few times before restarting a loop which begins with call to .WaitOne().

Some operating systems / compiler combinations allow this.  Some don't.

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Mutex has 2 state only: locked or unlocked. It can't be locked twice or unlocked twice. Something that you want is Semaphore: [See Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.semaphore(v=vs.110).aspx). Semaphore has counter and after each `WaitOne` counter decreases by 1, and after each call of `Release` counter increases by 1.

Comment: Not a semaphore, but a recursive mutex - those are different.

Answer (score 8):

The .NET `System.Threading.Mutex` class uses a Win32 kernel mutex object which is re-entrant.  The following note from [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.mutex) explains correct usage:

> The thread that owns a mutex can request the same mutex in repeated calls to `WaitOne` without blocking its execution. However, the thread must call the `ReleaseMutex` method the same number of times to release ownership of the mutex.

Clearly then, the OS is counting the number of times the mutex is entered -- it is NOT a binary state of "locked or unlocked" (beside the count, there's an additional state of "abandoned").